# Live update relative time in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, nsdateformatter

In my SwiftUI app, I'm showing relative time as follows.

```
struct ContentView: View {

    let date: Double = 1589014112

    var body: some View {
        Text(Date(timeIntervalSince1970: date).relativeTime())
    }
}

extension Date {
    func relativeTime(in locale: Locale = .current) -> String {
        let formatter = RelativeDateTimeFormatter()
        formatter.unitsStyle = .full
        return formatter.localizedString(for: self, relativeTo: Date())
    }
}
```

I get the time interval since 1970 as double from an API. I want to show relative time in my app. The output is as below.

[image]

The view updates only when I reload and it stays at "10 seconds ago" with every passing second. How to update it in real time? I want to change whenever the current date (`Date()`) changes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use a TimerPublisher to trigger something periodically. 
Here is a quick example below;

```swift
struct PlaygroundView: View {

    let timer = Timer.publish(
        every: 1, // second
        on: .main,
        in: .common
    ).autoconnect()

    let date = Date()

    @State var secondStr: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        Text(secondStr)
            .onReceive(timer) { (_) in
                self.secondStr = self.date.relativeTime()
            }
    }
}

extension Date {
    func relativeTime(in locale: Locale = .current) -> String {
        let formatter = RelativeDateTimeFormatter()
        formatter.unitsStyle = .full
        return formatter.localizedString(for: self, relativeTo: Date())
    }
}
```

You can observe that the `secondStr` changes every second like 
1 seconds ago 
2 seconds ago 
and so on..

Answer (score 10):

### You can use SwiftUI Text's [init(_:style:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text/init(_:style:)) to accomplish this without timers.

```
let date: Double = 1589014112

var body: some View {
    Text(Date(timeIntervalSince1970: date), style: .relative)
}
```

**Availability:** iOS 14.0+, iPadOS 14.0+, macOS 11.0+, Mac Catalyst 14.0+, tvOS 14.0+, watchOS 7.0+.

Note: The available `style`s should be enough for most use cases, but they are somewhat limited. See [Text.DateStyle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text/datestyle).

Comment: You can mention that `DateStyle` is available only in iOS 14+, where Timers work from iOS 13

Comment: @Imthath I have updated the answer with your suggestion. Thanks!